# Criterion on object relation list field

Tags: ezpublish

Using eZ Publish 2014.11, I'd like to filter search results on an objectrelationlist field.

I use this code (I removed all parts that are not related to the objectrelatiolist field) :

```
        $query->query = new Criterion\LogicalAnd(
        array(
            // ...
            new Criterion\Field(  'myField', Criterion\Operator::EQ, my_value ),
            // ...
        )
    );
```

According to the profiler, the resulting query looks like this (I removed all parts that are not related to the objectrelatiolist field) :

```
SELECT 
-- ...
      AND `ezcontentobject`.`id` IN (
        SELECT 
          `contentobject_id` 
        FROM 
          `ezcontentobject_attribute` 
        WHERE 
          (
            -- ...
            AND (
              `contentclassattribute_id` IN ('342') 
              AND `sort_key_string` = my_value
            )
          )
      ) 
-- ...
```

Apparenty in the database sort_key_string is empty for the field row (in spite the existing relation shown in `data_text` field):

```
*************************** 385. row ***************************
   attribute_original_id: 0
contentclassattribute_id: 342
        contentobject_id: 137
              data_float: 0
                data_int: NULL
               data_text: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<related-objects><relation-list><relation-item priority="1" contentobject-id="67" contentobject-version="1" node-id="69" parent-node-id="2" contentclass-id="43" contentclass-identifier="theme" contentobject-remote-id="00162a519495cd3b956192ea30b68761"/><relation-item priority="2" contentobject-id="68" contentobject-version="1" node-id="70" parent-node-id="2" contentclass-id="43" contentclass-identifier="theme" contentobject-remote-id="853215e40ca057a787a8cea9cdd5ddce"/></relation-list></related-objects>

        data_type_string: ezobjectrelationlist
                      id: 614
           language_code: fre-FR
             language_id: 2
            sort_key_int: 0
         sort_key_string: 
                 version: 1
```

**So my question is : is there any way to search content using a criterion on an objectrelationlist ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I should have use the `fieldRelation` criterion like this :

```
new Criterion\FieldRelation(  'myField', Criterion\Operator::IN, array(my_value) ),
```

Comment: Sylvain is it possible to use FieldRelation  by specifying the field identifier and the the field value in the destination related content ? kind of
new Criterion\FieldRelation(  'myField', Criterion\Operator::EQ, array('title' => 'test') ),